# What are the Disadvantages of unnecessary increase in PID gains?

Tags: signal, control, control-system, pid-controller, electrical

I read somewhere that if we increase the PID gains unnecessarily, it will cause more energy consumption of the controller and it will lead to noise and distortion in the practical. May someone please give me more explanation on this?? that how it lead to noise or distortion in practical??

Comment: What do you mean by "increase PID gains unnecessarily"?  What types of plants are you working with?  What are your metrics for performance and robustness?  More information would be helpful.

Comment: Increasing a forward path gain will increase controller output voltage and current and will try to accelerate the plant at a higher rate; response will be faster so viscous friction will increase, also amplifier saturation will cause non-linear effects.

Comment: @Chu Thanks for your reply, this is what exactly i am looking for, May you please give more information on this, such as how it happens and what are its effects on the system in practice and what type of nonlinear effects it causes.

Answer (score 1):

If you tune the controller so that it enters a limit cycle or there is "hunting" due to a dead time in the plant you may increase energy consumption of the system (not the controller) if it takes energy to drive in both directions (for example active heat/cool or a servomotor).

Reducing the integral gain can help, in some cases it is set to zero.